# Whether $\inf_k \{a_k\}\ \left\lvert \sum_n b_n \right\lvert\ \leq\ \left\lvert \sum_n a_n b_n \right\lvert$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Sorry I imagine this is a stupid question, but I'm just not sure if this is true, and I don't know what to search on Google.

Is it true that $\inf_k \{a_k\}\ \left\lvert \sum_n b_n \right\lvert\ \leq\ \left\lvert \sum_n a_n b_n \right\lvert$? Does this hold if the only thing we know is $a_n > 0$ for all $n$? If not, what are the minimum requirements on the series for this inequality to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jasper Loy already pointed out that $a_n>0$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) is not a sufficient condition. But the inequality holds if both sequences are positive:

Let $a_n,b_n \geq 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we have by definition $$0 \leq \inf \{a_k; k \in \mathbb{N}\} \leq a_n  \tag{1}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, thus

$$\inf\{a_k; k \in \mathbb{N}\} \cdot \left| \sum_n b_n \right| = \sum_n \inf\{a_k;k \in \mathbb{N}\} \cdot b_n \stackrel{(1)}{\leq} \sum_n a_n \cdot b_n $$

Comment: Thank you and Jasper Loy for your answers. I should have stated that in my post, but I am looking for minimum requirements. It seems to me that $b$ positive is sufficient, but not necessary, is it?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_1=1,b_1=-2,a_2=2,b_2=1$ for a counterexample.